Will QFSE be ever fully replaced by ChatGPT?
Do you guys think it is inevitable? I think there are two aspects:

quality of answers: right now, ChatGPT sucks at answering complex math problems but it's probably only a question of time until it overtakes quants in its ability.

People might always nonetheless seek advice from other experienced humans: but then again, if 1) is true, then will there be any need for quants? (And therefore will there be any quant experienced humans left?)


Seems that the demise of QSE is inevitable?

My comments on https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/81118 : we might end up only with questions that LLMs can't answer yet. :)
